# Getting database info for a django template with ajax

Tags: html, ajax, django, database, templates

I'm very new to django and ajax, i'm trying to do the following:

- In my html i have a few "select" elements, and for every "select" there is a button called "view".
- When I click "view" i want to retrieve database info dependent on the option selected in the "select" corresponding to the clicked "view". This should be done by ajax, and i want to display some of said database info in the html (without refreshing the page obviously).

I understand i should add a onClick event to the buttons, and in there send the selected option info via ajax, what I'm confused about is the following:

- In such a scenario, should i use GET or POST? And why?
- What URL do i contact with AJAX? Should i create a special URL that will be used only for this function (and presumably won't be visited by the user in a normal way)?
- Once I already have the AJAX call, how exactly should i return the database info to the template? I would assume this is somehow done in the view corresponding to the URL i will be calling? Do i somehow use the "success" function in the javascript that calls AJAX?

The most relevant question here i found was this one [Django: Get database object value in template using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192916/django-get-database-object-value-in-template-using-ajax), but it doesn't clear all of my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular use case you should use GET. If you're using jQuery, which makes these things really easy you can use `$.GET()`.

Create a view that returns a JsonResponse and contact that with Ajax.

Yes. You'll use the success function in the jQuery GET and the response will contain a JSON serialized output from Django.

You can either build the JSON object yourself, or use a [Django serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/).

Comment: I see. Now after i pass what i want from the database back to the success function, how do i include this output in a template? Say i want my page to show a table with this data?

Comment: Use javascript to create the table and then append it to the html. `$('#yourdivcontainer').html(yourGeneratedTable);`